# How do i darken the whole page? ( html )

Tags: javascript, html

When i use an other div to do it, it will not affect other dom classes, so i have to modify each dom class when i want the whole page to get darker.

Is there a way to overlap the whole document with a gray transparent plane?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065927/button-to-darken-the-whole-page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/srikarg/full/pDzgj) ilustrating your needs. (creating a dismissable popup and dimming the view)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn btn-success dim">Dim the page!</button>
  <div class="dimmer">
    <span class="exit">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum vel itaque fuga fugit fugiat enim excepturi nihil aperiam soluta ex nemo quam consectetur blanditiis dolores quisquam temporibus voluptatem veritatis distinctio neque labore ullam dicta delectus aspernatur odio ipsam. Sit est tempora odit neque fuga sapiente velit aliquid dignissimos ratione perspiciatis animi ullam incidunt veritatis quo eligendi esse aperiam qui vitae praesentium nam! Necessitatibus sequi maiores facere non numquam nesciunt veniam dignissimos aperiam consectetur saepe excepturi mollitia id tempora vero labore ducimus impedit iusto perspiciatis aliquam optio distinctio debitis quibusdam nulla dicta repellat praesentium ullam cupiditate totam soluta voluptatibus blanditiis recusandae!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum vel itaque fuga fugit fugiat enim excepturi nihil aperiam soluta ex nemo quam consectetur blanditiis dolores quisquam temporibus voluptatem veritatis distinctio neque labore ullam dicta delectus aspernatur odio ipsam. Sit est tempora odit neque fuga sapiente velit aliquid dignissimos ratione perspiciatis animi ullam incidunt veritatis quo eligendi esse aperiam qui vitae praesentium nam! Necessitatibus sequi maiores facere non numquam nesciunt veniam dignissimos aperiam consectetur saepe excepturi mollitia id tempora vero labore ducimus impedit iusto perspiciatis aliquam optio distinctio debitis quibusdam nulla dicta repellat praesentium ullam cupiditate totam soluta voluptatibus blanditiis recusandae!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  padding: 2.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.dimmer {
  display: none;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.dim {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
  z-index: 200;
}

.exit {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var dimmerButton = $('.dim');
  var dimmer = $('.dimmer');
  var exit = $('.exit');
  dimmerButton.on('click', function() {
    dimmer.show();
  });
  exit.on('click', function() {
    dimmer.hide();
  });
});
```

Note: The author of this is @srikarg

Comment: The way opacity is done leaves the dimmer containers undesirably transparent. You probably want to use `rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` on the dimmer instead.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to show an overlay div

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Make it position fixed

```
#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

and make it visible when you want to darken the page, here is how you do it

```js
$(function(){
  //Am hiding the overlay after 2 sec
  $("#overlay").delay(3000).hide(200);
})
```

```css
 #overlay {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      position:fixed;
      left:0;
      top: 0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <h1>My Awesome Page</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `background-color` to your body with css:

```
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* your color */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6gahqaej/2

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that when i darken the whole page, i need to show a popup window with normal opacity. the darken page is there to indicate that the user should focus only on the window that poped up.