# How to dim everything on a webpage apart from a div - to bring attention

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently none of the already asked questions on this topic are of use, therefore I am asking a new one. I have a log in page, and I have a sign in button, which on click shows a div from being hidden after showing a loading gif for 2 seconds using the following function.

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('Login').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
},2000);

}
```

I am stuck on how I would go about dimming everything behind this div after clicking the sign in button.

My current form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="hello" onsubmit="showDiv(); return 
false;">
```

My sign in button

```
<input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="submit" 
name="submit" id="Login" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" 
border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv()">
```

Comment: the div with the form should be the size of the viewport and have a transparent black background. and it needs a higher z-index than everything else.

Comment: What about dimming everything else?

Comment: z-index is used to layer elements, so a higher z-index means everything with a lower z-index is behind it. thus using a transparent coloured background has the effect of dimming anything that's behind it..

Comment: Okay thanks, so would you be able to give me some code examples please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i darken the whole page? ( html )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160995/how-do-i-darken-the-whole-page-html)

Comment: that link doesn't help me in the slightest, as I said at the start

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're trying to make a modal. To dim everything on the page:

Create an element on the page

```
<div class="covering-panel">
    // form goes here
</div>
```

and give it a fixed position, where the height and width cover the screen.

```
.covering-panel {
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);  // opaque black
    height: 100vh;                 // height of the viewport
    position: fixed;               // always cover the screen
    width: 100%;                   // width of the viewport
    z-index: 30;                   // stay on top of other elements
}
```

Put the form inside the `.covering-panel` div and use javascript to hide show the whole element.