# How to darken everything on a page apart from a div on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sign in button that uses the function -

```
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('SteamLogin').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
  }, 2000);
}
```

to show a loading gif, and then unhide a div. I would like to know if there is something I can add to end of this function which darkens everything behind the DIV that shows up, to bring attention to the pop up. Any current questions asked about this are really of no use to me and I have tried everything. If anyone has any ideas, I am very new to CSS and HTML so any help will be appreciated in simple terms.

UPDATE: Still really need help if anyone can assist.

My button that I want to dim the page after showing the loading gif and unhiding the div is here, I want to dim everything behind the div.

```
<input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" 
name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" 
border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv();">
            <div class="mainLoginLeftPanel_signin">
```

Comment: You can have a absolutely positioned `div` behind the signin `div` and on top of the rest of the elements with 100% width and height, black background with a little bit of opacity (eg `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)`) and fade that in and out.

Comment: didn't you ask the same question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496507/how-to-dim-everything-on-a-webpage-apart-from-a-div-to-bring-attention)?

Comment: Yes but I had no success

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with pure CSS.

I use [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) to achieve the desired result

As for the overlay - or *darkening*, I use an empty anchor tag with `z-index` stacking to create a clickable overlay which only shows up when the modal is open. Clicking the overlay closes the modal.

The modal also has a separate close button.

When the modal is closed it doesn't interfere with the body content.

**Responsive Example:**

```css
/* essential code */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.closeoverlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closebutton {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal:target>.closeoverlay {
  display: block;
}

.modal>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 75vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #dedede;
  z-index: 3
}

.wrap,
.modal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.modal-content {
  overflow-y: auto
}


/*demo fluff */

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  margin: 2em 0 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closebutton:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clutter,
.modal-content p {
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.clutter {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#M"><button>Open Modal</button></a>
  <div id="M" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a class="closebutton" href="#">&times;</a>
      <p>Prosciutto leberkas boudin pastrami sausage pork. Hamburger pancetta jowl venison pastrami. Filet mignon alcatra burgdoggen salami, ham hock shoulder pork loin sirloin jowl </p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="closeoverlay"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clutter">Bacon ipsum dolor amet shoulder sausage rump venison kevin prosciutto salami shank. Venison salami flank doner burgdoggen, shoulder beef sausage swine alcatra short loin pig chuck. Pastrami sirloin shoulder, swine frankfurter beef strip steak sausage
  salami tri-tip. Prosciutto leberkas boudin pastrami sausage pork. Hamburger pancetta jowl venison pastrami. Filet mignon alcatra burgdoggen salami, ham hock shoulder pork loin sirloin jowl picanha flank drumstick pancetta. Turkey shoulder cupim rump
  ball tip strip steak turducken tri-tip biltong pork doner. Turducken leberkas chuck filet mignon bresaola picanha ball tip pig ground round shankle. Shank pork ribeye fatback, capicola pork loin tri-tip porchetta biltong landjaeger ham hock hamburger.
  Strip steak pork chop sirloin</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector tag :not

```
*:not(div) {
color: black;
background-color: black;
//set any other that should be darkened
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can made something like twitter does, its create a div that will fill the whole page:

```
<div class="PermalinkOverlay" id="permalink-overlay" style="display: block;">
      <!-- Content that will be showed whenever you want -->
</div>
```

And set a default style for it:

```
.PermalinkOverlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1010;
}
```

So every moment that you want to give a darker transparent background to you site, you cant just put the display block to .PermalinkOverlay class. To hide it, will can set the display to none, just like you already do.